# Mock a method of a specific class instance in pytest tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, oop, pytest, pytest-mock

I can't figure out how to mock the method of a specific instance of a class.

I have the following class instances in my code

```
myInstance = MyCustomClass()
myInstanceToMock = MyCustomClass()
```

In a test, I would like to mock a method of the second one but not the first.
I can manage to mock the method for both by doing something like that:

```
import pytest

def the_mocked_method():
    pass

def test_something(mocker):
     mocker.patch.object(MyCustomClass, "the_method", new=the_mocked_method)
```

The problem is that both `myInstance` and `myCustomInstance` are affected and that doesn't fit my usecase.

Any way to mock only a method of a specific existing instance ?

Comment: If `myInstance` and `myInstanceToMock` are just local variables - no, there is no way, as these are created anew each time at runtime.

Comment: Are these global variables or how are you using them? You might be able to use `patch.object(myInstanceToMock, ...)` if you have access to those variables from the test.